# Show image on solr search result page

Tags: media, search

I want to show image in my solr search result page.
For that, I have created one field in my content type called media.

In db, Images are saving in field_data_field_media table in the form of field_media_value

Any help very much appreciated.

Best,
Latika

Comment: Can you please add tag of Drupal version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered helping yourself with this similar question?

[showing an image field from solr index on custom solr search page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72186/showing-an-image-field-from-solr-index-on-custom-solr-search-page)

To display image in your search-result.tpl.php you can follow below link also.

https://www.drupal.org/node/953096

Comment: I tried both. It's not working for me. Mu image is not in CCK editor. I have created one field. How I get this image/image path/nid ?

Comment: Are you saying that you are not getting image field which you have indexed for content type in search results in solr? Is your relation correct there?